# Directive nesting through parents in UL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When i place a binding within the directive below, in a UNSORTED LIST. It will iterate through all the parent nodes.

This only happens though while using bindings within a compile directive...

An example is using this tree view directive.

please note i had to modify the bottom script.

http://jsfiddle.net/8LWUc/1709/

```
(a,g,c)

a = scope g= element c= attrs
```

Notice on console, the binding will activate for every parent node....

If anyone has any tips as to how to isolate the right click to the node, please let me know! I am currently not being able to figure out how.

Any help is greatly appreciated, update the fiddle as you wish please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contextmenu` event bubbles up to the parents from the origin that is wht you are seeing this behavior. You could just stop the event from bubbling using `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
g.bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    a.$apply(function () {
        // Your angular stuff here
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qa78a7zk/)**

Comment: I have no idea how you figured stopPropagation... or how you stumbled upon it. But thank you very much!